# Why am I generating an undefined reference to _fe_dfl_env in 64-bit Cygwin

Tags: c, gcc, cygwin, fenv

```
$ cat test.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fenv.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  fesetenv(FE_DFL_ENV);
}

$ gcc -o a.exe test.c
/tmp/ccxbZr33.o:test.c:(.rdata$.refptr._fe_dfl_env[.refptr._fe_dfl_env]+0x0): undefined reference to `_fe_dfl_env'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

$ nm /bin/cygwin1.dll | grep _dfl_
00000001801c2728 D _fe_dfl_env
000000018029e5e0 b _ZL10fe_dfl_env
```

I did some looking around on the web and found this:
http://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin-cvs/2013-q1/msg00093.html

Some more information:

`$ cygcheck -cd | grep gcc
gcc-core                   4.8.1-3
gcc-fortran                4.8.1-3
gcc-g++                    4.8.1-3
gcc-objc                   4.8.1-3
gcc-objc++                 4.8.1-3
gcc-tools-epoch1-autoconf  2.59-2
gcc-tools-epoch1-automake  1.9.6-2
gcc-tools-epoch2-autoconf  2.64-2
gcc-tools-epoch2-automake  1.11.6-1
libgcc1                    4.8.1-3
mingw-gcc-debuginfo        4.7.3-1
mingw64-i686-gcc-debuginfo 4.8.1-2`

`$ uname -a
CYGWIN_NT-6.2 Raven 1.7.25(0.270/5/3) 2013-08-31 20:37 x86_64 Cygwin`

Comment: You shall use `<>` brackets to `#include` system headers.

Comment: Links on `CYGWIN_NT-6.1-WOW64 xxx 1.7.20(0.266/5/3) 2013-06-07 11:11 i686 Cygwin`.

Comment: urgg, spot anything obviously wrong in my stack?

Comment: ahh, just noticed that you're using 32-bit Cygwin.  As far as I can tell, this is a 64-bit issue.